# reset min value of oracle sequence to max value of primary key

Tags: oracle, sequence

My Goal: I want to create a procedure where the min value of the
sequence will start at the max value primary key column in a table. So
that I can use this sequence to populate my primary key columns in ETL
maps without any constraint errors. Below is the code I'm trying to
work on, but I keep getting too many errors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SET_MDM_IPEDS_SEQ
(P_NAME  IN VARCHAR2,P_VAL IN OUT NUMBER)
IS
V_NUM  NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(IPEDS_ORG_LND_KEY),0) INTO P_VAL FROM MDM_IPEDS_ORG_LND;
SELECT MDM_IPEDS_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL INTO V_NUM;
ALTER SEQUENCE MDM_IPEDS_SEQ INCREMENT BY V_VAR;
SELECT MDM_IPEDS_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL INTO V_NUM;
ALTER SEQUENCE MDM_IPEDS_SEQ INCREMENT BY 1;
END;
\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the ALTER SEQUENCE commands inside of an 'execute immediate'.